# Changing and deleting Things via Flattr API?

Tags: flattr

There are calls to create a Thing via the Flattr REST API.

But is there a way to update or delete existing Things via REST?

Answer (score 1):

Editing things is not possible with the current version of the API.
It will however be possible in the next version which we will release in the *near* future.

Answer (score 1):

We just released a new API the other day where you can update things.

http://developers.flattr.net/v2/